# Reading real & imaginary values from file & forming a complex variable using complex class in c++

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I have one text files which stores real part & imaginary part of the complex number, one after the other in a single column. ie. Every odd entry is real, every even entry is imaginary. I want to read these values & make a complex number using complex class in c++ but having difficulty assigning the real & imaginary part.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    ifstream fp_data;
    int i=0;
    double data=0;
    complex<double> Complex_Signal[10];

    fp_data.open("Complex_data.txt");
    if (!fp_data) 
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
        exit(1); // terminate with error
    }

    while (fp_data >> data) 
    {
        switch(i%2)
        {
            case 0: Complex_Signal[i].real() = data;
                break;
            case 1: Complex_Signal[i].imag() = data;
                break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    fp_data.close();

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout << Complex_Signal[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting **error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment**. How to do it?

Comment: Change `Complex_Signal[i].real() = data;` to `Complex_Signal[i].real(data);` You can read about that in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Every odd entry is real, every even entry is imaginary

That does not match what your code does. It has the real part first (at even). I assume that your code does the correct thing.

You need to use the setter versions of `real` and `imag`:

```
Complex_Signal[i].real(data);
Complex_Signal[i].imag(data);
```

You could also read both from the file at once (since they come in pairs) and put them in the array at the same time:

```
double real, imag;
while(fp_data >> real >> imag) {
    Complex_Signal[i] = {real, imag};
    ++i;
}
```

Your `while` loop will however not terminate when you have read 10 pairs so it will run into *Undefined Behaviour* if you have more than 10 pairs in the file. An alternative solution could be to use a `std::vector` to read as many pairs as you really have in the file.

```
#include <complex>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// using namespace std; // bad practise

int main() {
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> Complex_Signal;

    if(std::ifstream fp_data{"Complex_data.txt"}) {
        double real, imag;
        while(fp_data >> real >> imag) {
            Complex_Signal.emplace_back(real, imag);
        }
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for(auto& sig : Complex_Signal) {
        std::cout << sig << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use right public member function for set data:

```
...
switch(i%2)
{
     case 0: Complex_Signal[i].real(data);
         break;
     case 1: Complex_Signal[i].imag(data);
         break;
}
...
```

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/imag/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/real/

Comment: You should use https://en.cppreference.com as the reference documentation. From my experience it's more up-to-date and reliable.

Comment: No problem) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/imag